# Translating from Z3Py to SMT-LIB

Tags: z3, z3py

Please let me know how to translate the following line from Z3Py to SMT-LIB:

```
def _to_octonion(a):
if isinstance(a, OctonionExpr):
    return a
else:
    return OctonionExpr(a, RealVal(0), RealVal(0), RealVal(0), RealVal(0), RealVal(0), 
                        RealVal(0), RealVal(0))
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: *it can't be done*.
Z3Py is the Z3 API on top of Python (a programming language that contains a bunch of conveniences for users). On the other hand, SMT-LIB 2.0 is a formula exchange format, and is very limited. SMT-LIB 2.0 files are usually generated by other programs that need to interact with SMT solvers. 
Note that the function above does not even "type-check" in the SMT-LIB 2.0 format.
The input can be an `OctonionExpr` or "anything else" and the output is an `OctonionExpr` (or an exception).

Comment: Then your program for complex numbers and the extensions for other hyper-complex numbers only work under Z3Py? There is not possible to  adapt them for Z3 SMT?.  Many thanks

Comment: We can adapt, but it will not be as nice to use as the Z3Py version. For example, we will not be able to overload operators such as `+` and `*`. "Automatic coercions" (e.g., `_to_octonion` or `_to_complex`) will not be applied automatically for us. For example, `x*x + 2 == 0` is succinct to write because we are using operator overloading, coercions (the `2` is converted into a complex expression), etc.

Comment: I see and then I can understand how wonderful Z3Py is.  Congratulations and many thanks.